# What is the difference between 听 and 听力|?

Tags: word-choice

Hello I'm learning Chinese and I would like to know when I have to use only 听 and when 听力?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

听 is a verb, for example 听歌 (listen to a song).

听力 is a noun: the ability to hear